# Text Field Style Crashes on Android Devices in an app with Sencha

Tags: android, sencha-touch, textfield

I am having problems with the default style of Sencha (or Android not sure) for the text inputs and password fields, it works ok on iOS devices and on some android devices, but HTC and others put their awful default style (white background and grey border) which i can nohow change or hide. Because of that all the layout looks very awful.... 
[see the image please.](http://www.flickr.com/photos/76912779@N08/6898479772/)
Even the sample of Sencha Touch has the same problem.
[see please the second image here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/76912779@N08/7044576267/).
Please if you have any suggestion what is the reason of it or how it is possible to hide i 
would be very grateful!! here is all i have tried for that

```
input { 
background: transparent !important; 
border: 0 transparent !important; 
-webkit-appearance: none; 
} 
input[type=text] { 
background: transparent !important; 
border: 0 transparent !important; 
-webkit-appearance: none; 
}
input:focus{ 
outline:none; 
background: transparent !important; 
border-color: transparent !important; 
-webkit-focus-ring-color: transparent; 
-webkit-appearance: none; 
}
```

Thanks in advance
Andrei

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing is actually an Android "feature" that generates a native control on top of your styled input field.

If you try to move your field on focus you should see that the field is intact, try the following css rule to see the phenomena:

```
input:focus {
    position: absolute;
    left: -20px;
}
```

What you could do is try to set `-webkit-user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only;` which works on some phones (not sure about < 2.3), but can break some functionality. E.g. for a number field you still get a qwerty-keyboard instead of a number pad etc.

So try it out, hopefully it helps you and is suitable for your needs.